# Basic Salesforce query

Tags: licenses, dashboard

I need to implement Salesforce.com in a company which sells computer hardware. how many licenses to I need if the users are 5 in number. What edition of salesforce.com would be apt if I want to have dashboard and summaries for the top management every month. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement stated above, You can either use professional or enterprise edition. If you just have 5 users then you just need 5 license as per requirement.